# Markdown: not display directory as link

Tags: markdown

I want to show some `directories` on a website using markdown. However, the `directory` is shown as link. How can I prevent that? Example:

```
file:///C:**/Program Files/**ccs/config_installation
```

Comment: Using which Markdown processor? That string isn't automatically linked on GitHub Gist, Dillinger.io, or StackEdit.io.

Answer (score 0):

You should display it as a **preformatted text**, like you did in your example.

It also helps with readability, especially for longer URLs.